# How to use the findItemsAdvanced tool of eBay API and get more than 100 entries?

Tags: python, ebay-api, python-3.10

I know that with eBay's API we can't make a call that provides more than 100 entries.
That's why I tried to make several calls with different `pageNumber` in order to get 100 entries multiplied by the number of page i decided to choose.

But at the second call (the call with `pageNumber=2`), I have the following exception error:

> for item in response.reply.searchResult.item:
> AttributeError: 'ResponseDataObject' object has no attribute 'item'

Please, do you know how to solve it?

Here is my code:

```
from ebaysdk.finding import Connection as Finding    
api = Finding(appid="XXX", config_file=None, siteid="EBAY-FR")    
keywords=str(input("What keywords do you want to use ? : "))    
for page in range(1,5):    
    request={
            "keywords": keywords,
            "paginationInput": 
                {
                    "entriesPerPage": 100,
                    "pageNumber": page
                }
            }

    response = api.execute('findItemsAdvanced', request)

    paginationOutput = response.reply.paginationOutput
    print(paginationOutput)

    for item in response.reply.searchResult.item:
        try:
            title=item.title
            price=float(item.sellingStatus.convertedCurrentPrice.value)
            listingType = item.listingInfo.listingType
            url=item.viewItemURL
                
            if price>0 and price<400 and listingType=="FixedPrice":
                print("title : ", title)
                print("price : ", price)
                print("url : ", url, "\n")

        except:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I stumbled upon this post myself, the answer is that the API call is returning 0 items on page 2 - findItemsAdvanced seems to return a small number of product listings even when doing a direct eBay search equivalent yields 100s-1000s. In your case, it may return up to 100 items on page 1, and then none on page 2.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).